# MVC connection string: An error occured while processing your request

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, iis, connection-string, plesk

I'm new to Windows server and have no idea how to create connection string on my IIS for my website. I've already created my MVC website and it's working fine on my localhost.

But when I run it on IIS server in Plesk Panel, it gives an error:

> An error occured while processing your request.

This happens whenever I try to make request to DB. When I want to sign up I face the error above.

Here's my connection string that I'm using:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;user=myDbUser;pwd=myDbPass; Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: are you using windows azure cloud service ?

Comment: Have you also moved your database to a dbserver that the IIS can reach?

Comment: @andreasnico: I'm using DbContext class. And I have created database in server.

Comment: @REDEVI_: no, I'm not using azure cloud.I'm using windows server.

Answer (score 0):

In Data Source="Enter your server Name Here" If you still got an error share your error screen.

Comment: Here are the screenshots of my problem. When I try to register an account from 1st screenshot it gets me to the second screenshot.  http://imgur.com/a/eUTtg

Comment: How could you realize that the problem in your connection string ?
and please share information. are u use entity framework if yes can u copy app.config connection string to web.config file